# Content Items are not cached (using XC9 update-1)

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I am having some performance issues with XC9, when I check the log file it contains many entries like:

```
79 16:57:42 INFO Core.MemCache.CE.Miss.ContentItem: ItemKey=Entity-ContentItem-d14d0772-6dc3-4e48-ae96-f8b8cb8a8887
69 16:57:42 INFO Management.block.getitembyid.d14d0772-6dc3-4e48-ae96-f8b8cb8a8887: Language=en
```

I have a caching policy for `Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Content.ContentItem` of type `#Sitecore.Commerce.Core.Caching.EntityMemoryCachingPolicy`.

I am using the Shops Environment.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ContentItem are apparently not cached by the Content-Item cache, but by the `ManagementCachePolicy`. I added the following cache policy:

```
{
        "$type": "Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Management.ManagementCachePolicy, Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Management",
        "AllowCaching": true,
        "Expiration": 3600000
}
```